# What is the best procedure to refactor an iOS app into a framework and a test app?

Tags: ios, git, frameworks, refactoring

I have an app that I've been using to develop some ideas that now seem to belong into a reusable framework (a lib). The whole thing is in a local git repo. I've lots of classes that belong to a lib and a some other classes that use them and present views for testing.

I want to move out the test code and leave a library and a separate app for testing. Have you done this? Do you have stumbled into something specific? Any advise?

Of course I could just move everything piecewise into different projects but I'd like to evolve the thing so I don't lose my GIT history and everything is seamless..

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to develop libraries, use submodules or subtrees. Subtrees is a contribution project to git. Submodules come with it out of the box. Check http://progit.org/book for more info on submodules.